# Is there a special way to grant read access to objects in an Auto-Launched Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, executioncontext

Original post: I have created an auto-launched flow that runs as "System Context Without Sharing--Access All Data" and is using apiVersion 50.0. This flow can get records from some objects, but not others.
Some examples:

- Cannot get records:

  - Account
  - Case
- Can get records:

  - Knowledge_DataCategorySelection
- Sometimes can get records:

  - CollaborationGroup

I don't understand why the Case and Account objects can't be read in this flow when the "System Context Without Sharing--Access All Data" setting should bypass any kind of permissions. However, the most confusing part is our Get Records component for the CollaborationGroup object that intermittently fails to find any records with the same filter between different runs of this flow.
Our Get Records component for CollaborationGroup has a filter on the name field and even if we call this flow with the same group name sometimes it will find records, sometimes it will not. This is happening in our Production Org, as well as our development sandboxes. Running the same flow in debug will result in different results between different runs. Has anyone experienced any issues getting records with the CollaborationGroup object (or any other object) in flows, when they are using the "System Context Without Sharing--Access All Data" setting?

Also note: As a backup plan/workaround, I created an invocable method that I can call from the flow that does a SOQL query (with sharing) and can get the records every time. I feel this is ignoring what is really happening here.

The workaround code:

```
public with sharing class CollaborationGroupHelper {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Collaboration Group' description='Gets a Collaboration Group ID for flow bug.' category= 'Group')
    public static List<CollaborationGroup> GetPart(List<string> groupNames) {
        List<CollaborationGroup> collabGroups = new List<CollaborationGroup>();
        for(string groupName : groupNames)
        {
            collabGroups.add([SELECT Id FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name = :groupName]);
        }
        return collabGroups;
    }
}
```

The two components getting CollaborationGroup records in my flow:

- The Apex Action is the workaround code above.
- The built in Get Records component that is failing to find records at times.

[image]

The result:

- The apex action always finds the record.
- This time the get records component didn't find any records. But sometimes it will find the record even if we are looking for the same group.

[image]

Update: the apex class workaround mentioned below no longer works after we have been error free for over 3 weeks. We are opening a ticket with Salesforce.

Update 2: We've narrowed down the source of the issue to the "System" user's access. We have some case automations (like email-to-case) that create cases. The user used for these automations is set in the setting Support Settings -> Automated Case User. You have an option for "System" or picking any user in your Org. We have the Automated Case User set as System. However, system does not have access to the CollaborationGroup records. I opened up a new question to specifically address this: [Why doesn't the System user have access to the CollaborationGroup records?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/359479/why-doesnt-the-system-user-have-access-to-the-collaborationgroup-records)